# Trying to optimize rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My current code is:

```
first_three_posts = Post.first(3)
last_three_posts = Post.last(3)
```

This makes the server hit twice.
Any way I can reduce it to one query

Comment: Do you want last and first posts in same AR object?

Comment: Yes @cnnr, in the same AR object

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the first and last elements of an ordered table, the only option (**very unsuggested**) you have to execute a single query is extracting the whole dataset, and getting the head and tail from the resulting collection in ruby itself.

Needless to say, unless your Post collection is very small, it is much faster to just run 2 different queries.